# I cant define an array containing an object typed values ?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, class, object

I have a class called `Challenges` which is defined as follow :

```
class Challenges {

    var title : String?
    var description : String?
    var points : Int?
    var status : String?
    var img :String?

    init (title : String ,description : String , point : Int , status : String , img : String){

        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.points = point
        self.status = status
        self.img = img
    }
}
```

And then I am trying to create an instance of it :

```
 var test = Challenges(title: "indoor", description: "hard", point: 123 , status: "Done", img: "img.com")
```

and then I want to put the instance in an array :

```
var holdChallenges : [Challenges] = [test]
```

Then I got the following error : 
`Cannot use instance member 'bounds' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available`

so I changed it to :

```
lazy var holdChallenges : [Challenges] = [self.test]
```

and then I am getting the following error :

> Value of type NSObject has no value member test

Comment: *Where* do you define the `test` and `holdChallenges` variables?

Comment: Also there is no "instance member 'bounds'" anywhere in your code. Please show a real self-contained example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Why are your properties optional when the initialiser requires non-optional values? As these are the values that will be used it seems pointless to have the optional types for the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Anwer is there  **property initializers run before 'self' is available**  so  so you make the wrong declaration

Because you are trying to initialize one property(variable) with another during the initialization process. At this time variables are not available yet.

so you can do this

```
 var test = Challenges(title: "indoor", description: "hard", point: 123 , status: "Done", img: "img.com")

    // one way

    var holdChallen :[Challenges ] = [Challenges(title: "indoor", description: "hard", point: 123 , status: "Done", img: "img.com")]

    // second way

    var holdChallenges : [Challenges] {

        return [test]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return `[test]` via [computed property](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) like this:

```
var holdChallenges: [Challenges] {
    return test
}
```

Or via `lazy` property:

```
lazy var lazyHoldChallenges: [Challenges] = {
    return [self.test]
}()
```